# Execute javascript confirm in swiftui using WKWebView

Tags: javascript, swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I'm currently trying to wrap a rails app in a webview so I can get native push notification functionality. I'm having troubles trying to figure out how to get javascript confirm and alerts working when using swiftui.

Heres what I got so far:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    return webView
  }

  func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    let appUrl = "http://localhost:3000"

    if let url = URL(string: appUrl) {
       let request = URLRequest(url: url)
       webView.load(request)
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

This works loading the app, everything appears to work fine except alerts and confirm dialogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with https://github.com/lazaronixon/react-native-turbolinks. At least now I can just use javascript rather than learning swift and kotlin/java.